# Repeated Outputs in C# Automatic Backup script

Tags: c#, repeat

I have created an automatic backup script from multiple online sources and my own limited knowledge of C# and for some reason it is repeating the first Write Line? Could someone please help me, I'm sure it's a stupid error but I don't know anyone that's good at C#. Here's the code:

New to stack overflow and vb/c# so sorry for stupid errors if there are any.

I did have trys and catches too but I removed them in the hopes that they were causing the issue but they weren't.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy");
        string Source = @"G:\Personal\A1";
        string Destination = @"D:\_Lil USB Backup\" + date;
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Source))
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Destination))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Destination);
            }
            CopyAllFiles(Source, Destination);
            Console.WriteLine("Task Completed successfully.");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source does not exist, try plugging the USB in dips**t.");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    private static void CopyAllFiles(string Source, string Destination)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Source);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(Destination, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(Destination, subdir.Name);
            CopyAllFiles(subdir.FullName, temppath);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully copied files.");
    }
}
```

Output to console:
Successfully copied files.
Successfully copied files.
Successfully copied files.
Task Completed successfully.

Expected output to console:
Successfully copied files.
Task Completed successfully.

(The files are copied correctly though).

Comment: because you are recursively calling your function CopyAllFiles for every subdirectory, do you have 3 folder deep

Comment: I'm new to this sorry, how do I close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CopyAllFiles()` recursively calls `CopyAllFiles()`, and the WriteLine() statement gets invoked for each call.  So, the output you see matches the code and my expectations.

The simplest solution I see is to move

```
Console.WriteLine("Successfully copied files.");
```

out of `CopyAllFiles()` and into the `Main()` function.